# Sign up algorithm for quiz; program not checking if username already existing

Tags: python

I am creating a quiz algorithm which utilities a log in system. For the sign up process, the usernames and passwords are stored in a text file and are read in order to see if they already exist.If this is the case, the user is told that the username or password already exists and this is repeated until something that doesn't already exist is input. When this happens,the text file is appended to add the username. For some reason however, the program doesn't check if the user attempt is already in the text file,but just adds it to the text file, even if it already exists.

The log in procedure, which does the first part of checking if a string is the same in both the variable and text file works just fine. The program checks if the username and password are in the files and if they are it logs in. The hashed code is used for testing and will be removed when the program works.

```
##Sign up

 if Option == ("2"):
     exit = False

     while exit == False:
      Userattempt = input("Please enter a username:\n>>> ")
      file = open("Usernames.txt","r")
      searchline = file.readline()
      Flag = False
      Username = ""

      for line in file:
          print(Userattempt, line)# used to see how the program goes through each line
          Username = str(line)
          if Userattempt == Username:
              Flag = True
              print("Yes", Userattempt, line)# Used to test after each line
          else:
              print("False")# Used to test after each line
          if Flag == True:
             print("That Username already exists, Please try another")
          else:
             #file.close()
             file = open("Usernames.txt","a")
             file.write(Userattempt)
             file.write("\n")
             print("Okay",Userattempt, "is your username")

             exit = True
             file.close()
```

This program runs fine, but for some reason it doesn't check if the user input is equal to each line and if it does,the flag used to catch that the username or password already exists isn't changed.

Comment: Can you give a small sample of the contents in Usernames.txt?

Comment: What is `searchline` for? You're skipping the first line of the file in the `for` loop.

Comment: `line` has a newline at the end, you need to use `strip()` to remove it.

Comment: Instead of `while exit == False:`, use `while True:`, and then use a `break` statement to stop the loop.

Comment: The `if Flag == True:` statement should be at the end of the `for` loop, not each time through the loop.

Comment: you can break out of the `for` loop as soon as you find a matching line.

Comment: Thank you for your help Barmar, just out of curiosity what do you mean by line has a newline at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it's not working is that you didn't remove the newline from the line being read from the file, so it never matches the user input.

You have other problems with the program logic. You shouldn't write the new username inside the `for` loop, because you don't know if the username is available until you get to the end of the file.

Instead of the `Flag` variable, you can use the `else:` block of the `for` loop. This will run if the loop completes normally instead of from a `break` statement. Then you `break` out of the loop when finding a matching line in the file.\

It's generally best to use a `with` statement to open a file and automatically close it when done.

```
##Sign up

if Option == ("2"):
     while True:
         Userattempt = input("Please enter a username:\n>>> ")
         with open("Usernames.txt","r") as file:
             for line in file:
                 Username = line.strip()
                 print(Userattempt, Username)# used to see how the program goes through each line
                 if Userattempt == Username:
                     print("That Username already exists, Please try another")
                     break # break out of for-loop
             else: # name not found, so add it
                 with open("Usernames.txt","a") as outfile:
                     outfile.write(Userattempt)
                     outfile.write("\n")
                     print("Okay",Userattempt, "is your username")
                break # break out of while-loop
```